# VB6 Access update query not updating table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6, vba

I am trying to add a number sequentially to a field for a job number in a do loop. My code is not breaking but it is not adding the records to the table. The code is written in a function that is being called when the access form button is pressed to update the records. Below is my code:

```
Dim NumofBatches As Integer
    NumofBatches = [Batches]
    Dim startnum As Integer
    startnum = 1
    Dim jobnum As String
    jobnum = [JobNumber]

    Do While startnum <= NumofBatches
        Dim mynumString As String
        mynumString = startnum
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Production (CardCode,JobItemNo,JobIndex,DrawingRef,DRDescription,[CreationDate],Quantity,FinishDate,LastLocation,DateLastMoved) VALUES ('" & jobnum & mynumString & "', ItemNumber, JobNumber, DrawingRef, DRDescription, [CreationDate], Quantity, FinishDate, LastLocation, DateLastMoved)"
        startnum = startnum + 1
    Loop
```

I realize I will have duplicated rows of fields except for the cardcode field which is what I am trying to achieve. The cardcode fields should be sequential in each row for the jobnumber. An example, 100011, 100012, where 10001 is the job number and it is adding 1, 2, etc. sequentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems. The first is in the field list in the INSERT part of your SQL statement. Unless you have a column in your Production table named "CardCode + mynumString" (and if you did it would have to have square brackets around it because it has a space and a symbol in it) it's not going to work. Inside the parentheses after `INSERT INTO <TableName>` you have to list column names from the table you are inserting into. Fix your target column names first.

Next you have a SELECT statement as the source of values you're inserting. Unless the values you need are found in a table, you should probably use a `VALUES` list:

```
INSERT INTO <TableName> (Col1, Col2, ...) VALUES (Val1, Val2, ...)
```

The final issue is that you have to concatenate your variables into the SQL string. I'm going to assume that [Text90] is a control with your CardCode value in it and you're wanting to concatenate it with mynumString. That would look something like this:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Production (Col1, Col2, ...) VALUES ('" & [Text90] & mynumString & "', Val2, ...)"
```

Note that you have to resolve your value outside of the quoted SQL string and concatenate that value into the string and set all of that off with single-tick quotes inside the SQL string.

I find it handy to build dynamic SQL strings like this using a variable and then execute it as:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL mySQLVariable
```

Having the SQL string in a variable makes it a little easier to spot errors in the concatenation if you inspect the variable during debugging or if you just dump the value to the immediate window with Debug.Print.

Comment: Nice answer. One small point is that you don't have to provide column names if you use all the columns in the table in order. (Perhaps that isn't true in Access? I forget.)

Comment: Thanks. I don't work with Access day to day any more, so I'm not sure, but IIRC it should work to skip the column specification on the target table if a value for each column is provided in the source either in the VALUES list or in a SELECT statement.

Comment: It certainly is true you can omit the column names, but as soon as the table contains an autonumber field, or even a calculated field, or gets an extra column, your query will fail, so providing them is a good practice imo

Comment: Sorry I am a few days late replying I appreciate your responses. My code still does not work with your suggestions. I updated my code in my question to reflect the new changes. I believe something may be wrong with how I am converting the sequential number to concatenate it with my string?

Comment: Your INSERT statement specifies a lot of columns and I think you really only want the one value to go into CardCode. In your VALUES group, all of the names after jobnum & mynumString are going to be inserted as literal names. What that means is that the statement will attempt to put the word "DateLastMoved" into the DateLastMoved column. If there's a value on your form that contains a date that you want in the DateLastMoved column, you will have to concatenate that into the VALUES part of the string too. You will have to do this for every column.

Comment: Thank you John for all your help. I was able to identify I had an extra comma in my insert statement and I was able to get this to work finally.